# Forcing WCF to ignore config file, or sections of config file

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I understand how to configure WCF programatically, but I'm wondering if there's a way to force a WCF service to always ignore the configuration file and/or to ignore parts of the configuration file.

I'd like to be able to restrict a service to using certain settings, such as ensuring it will only use a specific binding configuration whilst leaving some binding settings such as the address configurable. This means I have two options I can 1) Restrict specific settings as required if possible, or 2) Disable loading of the config file altogether and use my own custom config file that supports only the settings I need and use these as the basis on which to setup the bindings programatically based on these values.

I understand that with a self-hosted service I can at least iterate the binding settings and so forth and disable/remove/modify those I am not interested in after they have been loaded but I believe this is only trivial for self-hosted services where you set up ServiceHost manually and I'm wondering if it's the only way to restrict configuration especially as I believe that having made the service do this there is nothing to stop someone taking the service library itself and using a different host (such as IIS) to load it with their own custom configuration.

I understand that the whole point of WCF is that it's highly configurable and flexible and that this goes against this fundamental design goal of it somewhat so agree it's not an ideal scenario but this isn't a requirement I have had any input over so any suggestions as to how it may be possible to limit configuration options as discussed above would be appreciated.

Comment: How is your service being hosted? You seem to be concerned with someone stealing/hijacking your service and hosting it themselves. Is this correct?

Comment: Have you tried creating a custom ServiceBehavior?  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163302.aspx for description, they show an example on how to check for use of BasicHttpBinding

Comment: Yes, the issue is about retaining control of how the service can be hosted and limiting the ability of others to just host it in an arbitrary manner.

Comment: @GTG: Thanks, I'll have a read and see if this will do what I need.